# Shared Memory: SendMessage from VB6 to third-party DLL, retrieve data from passed struct?

Tags: c, api, sdk, shared-memory, sendmessage

An SDK tells me that, to retrieve certain data, my app needs to use SendMessage to pass a pointer to a C struct and then retrieve the data from the struct. My app is an entirely separate process. As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is by a memory-mapped file.

Is this correct or is there a better way?

If it is correct, what do I pass as the pointer? I've walked through the code at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/165942 and just don't see what I should pass.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could do with posting info or examine samples in the SDK.

But I am thinking you need to use the WM_COPYDATA message from what you are saying

See here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Zonder. I hoped that there was a generic answer to how an app can allocate memory that a third party app can write to.  The SDK is sketchy. It doesn't seem to answer this and it doesn't mention WM_COPYDATA.  I'll look at the SDK again to see if I can be more specific.

Comment: Well if you find any more details update your question.  Most things would use a socket these days or named pipe.  But you are stuck with the sdk's way of doing things